# Bootstrap: left and right alignment including a dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot get these 2 columns to align properly.

Any suggestions on how to get the first column left aligned, the second column right aligned, and still have the drop-down popup appear in the proper location?

Here is a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/HV42nstWTG

Comment: Inspecting the element `.pull-right>.dropdown-menu` I simply removed `right: 0;` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this. Change the order of the text link and dropdown, and use `pull-right` on both.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <!-- This column should be left-aligned on the screen -->
      <div class="col-md-2">
        left-aligned content should go here
      </div>
      <!-- the content in this column should be right-aligned on the screen -->
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <a href="#" class="pull-right">text for a link goes here</a> 
        <div class="dropdown pull-right"> 
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Support
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
          </ul>
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/GPbPh3Ajm1

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper around the dropdown.

Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- This column should be left-aligned on the screen -->
    <div class="col-md-2">
      left-aligned content should go here
    </div>
    <!-- the content in this column should be right-aligned on the screen -->
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="wrapper pull-right">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Support
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
          </ul> <a href="#">text for a link goes here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you! Learn something new every day...!

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, just remove - pull-right and added the md offset on the second column. This should work. Good luck!

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <!-- This column should be left-aligned on the screen -->
      <div class="col-md-2">
        left-aligned content should go here
      </div>
      <!-- the content in this column should be right-aligned on the screen -->
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-6">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Support
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
          </ul> <a href="#">text for a link goes here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```